# "Прикрепить" выступающую картинку к низу блока, а не к верху

Tags: css

Есть блок с фиксированной высотой и шириной. Задача в том, чтобы поместить в него картинку, которая будет немного выступать сверху, но только если она действительно больше этого блока. Если картинка по высоте меньше этого блока, то она должна прилипнуть к низу, а не к верху. Казалось бы задача может легко решится при помощи `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`, но тут ещё одна особенность: в ширину картинка также может быть совершенно любого размера и нужно, чтобы она автоматически центрировалась при помощи `text-align: center;` или `margin: auto;` и работал `width: auto`, что невозможно с абсолютным позиционированием.

Вот всё, что у меня сейчас есть: https://jsfiddle.net/dfrj0sn5/1/ Здесь картинка прилипает к верху блока и выступает снизу, нужно наоборот.

Как бы это решить при помощи css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет ничего проще:

```
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: но ведь ничего не изменилось о_О https://jsfiddle.net/dfrj0sn5/2/

Comment: Вы просили позиционирование по центру - получите. Что еще не так?

Comment: тайтл моего вопроса: “Прикрепить” выступающую картинку к низу блока, а не к верху

Comment: вот ещё одна цитата: "Здесь картинка прилипает к верху блока и выступает снизу, нужно наоборот."

Comment: Важно понимать какого блока `wrap` или `main`?

Comment: видимым является main блок, нужно чтобы и картинка визуально прикреплялась к его низу, сколько ещё будет вложенных невидимых блоков - не важно

Comment: хорошо, тогда почему вы позиционируете относительно `main` не картинку, а `wrap`? зачем такой огород?

Comment: это мой набросок для прикрепления, возможно он и не пригодится

Comment: В общем позиционирование `wrap` отрабатывает правильно. Проблема в том, что он может быть больше картинки. На мой взгляд он не нужен, но если вы хотите го оставить вот решение https://jsfiddle.net/1agk61jg/1/

Comment: да, это то, что нужно